# Microsoft Word : Formatting paragraphs

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2007.

I have a word resume with below content:

[image: Before]

How can I bring the Phone and Email lines to the top, so that they perfectly fit with the height of the Name above.

Something like this:

[image: After]

Also, how to position the underline properly?
How to increase or decrease the space between underline and the text above?

Answer (score 3):

Moving the text from the bottom of the line to the top makes it more difficult to control. For that reason, the easiest and quickest way for you to accomplish what you want is to create a table.

Here are the instructions:

1. Create a table consisting of two rows and two columns. So it will have four cells in total.
2. Click anywhere inside the table and in Table > Layout on the ribbon bar, click View Gridlines, so that it's easier to see what you are working with.
3. Click on properties on the Ribbon bar and under the Table tab, go to Borders and Shading. Under the Borders tab, click on None located on the left. Now, to the right, under the word Preview, there are mini square icons with a line in each one of them. Click on the third one that has a line at the bottom. You should see a line appear at the bottom in the large preview to the right of the mini icons. Now click OK and OK again.
4. Highlight the first column. So, you are selecting two rows from the first column. Right click on it and choose Merge cells.
5. Now right click on that cell or go to Table > Layout, and go to Alignment, and choose the one that reads: Align Bottom Left.
6. Now, to get the text entered in that same large cell (the one we merged) to appear all the way to the left, so that it starts where the line starts, right click on it choose Table Properties or click Properties on the Ribbon bar. Go to the Cell tab. Click on the word Options below. Uncheck the checkbox next to the words that read "Same as the whole table". For the box that reads Left, change the number there, (most likely 0.08) to 0.
7. For the second column, in each of the two cells, right align your text.
8. Optionally, you may wish to go to Table > Layout and click on View Gridlines to turn it off so that you can see the final result, or you can go to Print Preview.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do it would be to insert a 2X1 table (with no visible borders). Put the name in one cell and the contact info the other.

That will make it much easier to independently adjust the spacing, alignment, and formatting of the name and contact info.